# UTF-8 Char are not displaying in TableViewer SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, swt

I created TableViewer in that I'm setting table item text as following.

```
item.setText(0, String.valueOf((char) 255));
```

After running the program there is nothing displaying for above.

If I create `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` or `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.StyledText` and set that value then I'm getting `ÿ`

```
StyledText styledText = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER);
styledText.setText("Hello " + String.valueOf((char) 255));
```

I tried to set `StyledCellLabelProvider` but still no value is showing for  `String.valueOf((char) 255)`

I tried to run the application with `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` option but no help.

What I'm missing here?, why table not displaying UTF-8 char

Comment: Java strings always use UTF-16 rather than UTF-8 but this should still be OK. It may be the font used for the table.

Comment: I tried many different font but still I'm not getting the correct output. Same thing work for Text.

Comment: hahahah finaly I  tried with one more font and it worked. :)